# Spring Boot cache doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I trying to configure spring cache, but the method is executed still. I have the below code, and the civilStatus cache is not working. The method getCivilStatus() is executed always. Does Anybody know the reason?

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Autowired
private SocioDemographicInfoService socioDemographicInfo;


@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(           
            new ConcurrentMapCache("civilStatus");

    return cacheManager;
}
}   



@Service
public class SocioDemographicInfoService {



@Cacheable(value="civilStatus")
public Map<String, String> getCivilStatus(){
    log.info("Retrieving civilStatus");
    Map<String, String> civilStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("CatalogoEstadoCivil.csv").getFile());
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] cod = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            civilStatus.put(cod[0].trim(), cod[1]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return civilStatus;
}
}
```

}

Comment: The problem lies in your configuration. You are auto wiring your bean with caching into the configuration. This eagerly instantiates the bean and doesn't make it post processed for caching.

Comment: thank you so much for you answer. I want to load a file in the begining and caching it.  Do you know how can I develop it ?

Comment: Why would you need caching for that? You can just do that yourself without enable caching. Add a method in your `SocioDemographicInfoService` annotated with `@PostConstruct` which loads the file and fills the map. No need to use springs caching abstraction for that.

Comment: I would like a cache, because I need invoke getCivilStatus, several times and I thought caching getCivilStatus(), would be the best option.

Comment: you don't need it. Just load the file at startup to fill a map and let `getCivilStatus` return that map. You don't need the added complexity of a cache or AOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the AOP and caching complexity your usecase is a lot simpler. Just create a method that loads the file at startup and let your `getCivilStatus` return that map. A lot simpler.

```
@Service
public class SocioDemographicInfoService implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    private final Map<String, String> civilStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private ResourceLoader loader;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Retrieving civilStatus");
        Map<String, String> civilStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        Resource input = loader.getResource("classpath:CatalogoEstadoCivil.csv"));
        if (input.isReadable() ) {
            File file = input.getFile();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] cod = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                    civilStatus.put(cod[0].trim(), cod[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error reading file", e_;
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try { br.close() } catch( IOException e) {}
                }               
            }   
        }   
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCivilStatus() {
        return this.civilStatus;
    }

    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader loader) {
        this.loader=loader;
    }

}
```

Something like this should work. It loads your after the bean is constructed (this code can probably be optimized by using something like commons-io). Note I used Springs `ResourceLoader` to load the file.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this approach because it serves the purpose today but limit future enhancements such as time to live, overflow to disk and other features usually caching framework provide. Also this will involve lot of unwanted boiler plate code which would have handled by caching framwork.

Comment: There is no boiler plate code the code is the same as you wrote. So there is no boilerplate. Also if you don't need something now don't add the complexity for something you might ever need 10 years from now. Instead of using a `@PostConstruct` method you could also make your getter lazy however I really dislike the getter which does more then just get.

Comment: Thank M.Deinum, I have checked your code. But I load more than one file in my project, and for this reason I think is better use a cache. You are right I should optimize my code with commons-io. Thank you again.

Comment: Or use java8, makes it even easier. I still don't see the reason why you would need a elaborate caching strategy as it would only complicate things, a lazy getter would be enough in this case. Regarding all the other things of caching, that doesn't work with the caching solution you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using spring boot and setting up a server using a class something like this (given below). Add EnableCaching annotation on the same class and define CacheManager as given below, instead of a separate configuration class. That will make sure caching is enabled before your class get initialized.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath*:spring/*.xml" })
public class MyBootServer{

public static void main(String args[]){
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyBootServer.class, args);
}

@Bean(name="cacheManager")
public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
...// Your code
}
}
```

Nothing wrong in your over all code. I tested your configuration in [my spring boot sample code](https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample) and it works

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right. the problem was my configuration, I have changed the cacheManager and works fine.